# Pass value from one function to another to calculate with it

Tags: c

How can i pass a value from one function to another ?

I would like to give a value from one function to the other function.
In my Code I would like to give the value of year to the other function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void inputDate(){
    int day, month, year;
    printf("\nPlease enter the date:)");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d", &day, &month, &year);
    
    return year;
}
void ageCalculation(){
    int age;
    age = 2020 - year;
}

int main(){
    inputDate();
    ageCalculation();
}
```

What is now the Problem ?  I add a function to output the calculation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputDate(){
    int day, month, year;
    printf("\nPlease enter the date:)");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d", &day, &month, &year);
    
    return year;
}
void ageCalculation(int year){
    int age;
    age = 2020 - year;
return age;
   
}

void outputAge(int age){
     printf("The boy is  %d years old", age);
}


int main(){
    int year = inputDate();
    ageCalculation(year);
    outputAge(int age);
}
```

Comment: I love how your program will become obsolete a week after you posted the question (as we enter 2021)... :) ... also, `ageCalculation` should probably `return age;` and make sure that the birthday of the **current year** isn't in the future (a child born Dec. 31st 2010 might not be 10 years old on Dec. 24th 2020).

Comment: As well as accepting Tomer's answer (which means the answer solved the issue), I would recommend that you upvote his answer as well, I did (both because it was well written and because he took the time to update it and answer your second question)... you might also be interested in the comments I wrote down in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputDate(){
    int day, month, year;
    printf("\nPlease enter the date:)");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d", &day, &month, &year);
    
    return year;
}
void ageCalculation(int year){
    int age;
    age = 2020 - year;
}

int main(){
    int year = inputDate();
    ageCalculation(year);
}
```

Please see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r177gVzaw) a code running.

The issue in your second snapshot is that you don't assign the value into a variable. Another issue is that `ageCalculation` is defined void, while it should be an int. It should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputDate(){
    int day, month, year;
    printf("\nPlease enter the date:)");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d", &day, &month, &year);
    
    return year;
}

int ageCalculation(int year){
    int age;
    age = 2020 - year;
    return age;
}

void outputAge(int age){
     printf("The boy is  %d years old", age);
}


int main(){
    int year = inputDate();
    int age = ageCalculation(year);
    outputAge(age);
}
```

Comment: I really doubt that this example will solve the whole of the issue, as `ageCalculation` doesn't return the `age` value (which is also miscalculated and the program won't survive the new year)... **Sidenote**: since the function `ageCalculation` has no side-effects, the compiler will likely optimize it away, turning it into a `NOOP`...

Comment: @Myst, well, I have to agree with everything you said :) But I guess that this is just a beginner question that in reality will have a more complicated program that won't turn into a `NOOP`.

Comment: True... :) ... I wrote it also for OP to read, just to make sure they're aware of the extra issues that they didn't directly ask about..

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed [Tomer updated his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65440036/4025095). His answer is great and I upvoted it.

However, since I just finished adding comments to the code, here are my observations...

Note that `ageCalculation` should (will) return an `int`.

Some of the comments observe code fragility, but don't solve this fragility (that's up to you).

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* I didn't touch this, but this might not be the ideal way to do this. */
int inputDate() {
  int day, month, year;
  printf("\nPlease enter the date:)");
  /* what if they enter "3/6/2000"...? which one's the month? */
  scanf("%d.%d.%d", &day, &month, &year);
  /* should you add validation? what if they entered "-1.0.2222"...? */
  return year;
}

/* note that this function returns an `int` */
int ageCalculation(int year) {
  int age;
  /*
   * The following calculation is wrong, but I didn't fix it. Consider using
   * `gmtime`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime Then test for month
   * and day offsets as well.
   */
  age = 2020 - year;
  return age;
}

/* didn't touch this, but could be a "girl", consider "person" instead. */
void outputAge(int age) { printf("The boy is %d years old", age); }

int main(void) {
  if (1) {
    /* variation 1 (better): use a temporary variable, it's more readable. */
    int tmp = inputDate();
    tmp = ageCalculation(tmp);
    outputAge(tmp);
  } else {
    /* alternative 2: pass the result of each calculation directly. */
    outputAge(ageCalculation(inputDate()));
  }
}
```